# Referencing a field from $lookup via mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am currently working with mongoDB.
I have a collection called `Users` with the following document:

```
{
  _id: "5d93f338e602a10a38ad3588",
  userID: "1",
  email: "test@test.com",
  password: "password",
  firstName: "Tom",
  lastName: "Bombadil"
}
```

I also have a collection called `Posts`. with a document:

```
{
  _id: "5d93fddce602a10a38ad358a",
  postID: "1",
  userID: "1",
  postContent: "hello world"
}
```

I am able to 'join' these two with the following $lookup from Users:

```
{
  from: 'Posts',
  localField: 'userID',
  foreignField: 'useriD',
  as: 'usersPosts'
}
```

How can I write a Query to get the "postContent" of said Post? Something along the lines of:

```
db.Users.find($lookup :     {
      from: 'Posts',
      localField: 'userID',
      foreignField: 'useriD',
      as: 'usersPosts'
    } : userPosts[0]
```

Comment: Do you want to get the `postContent` of all posts of a user, or only get the `postContent` of the first `post` (with `userPosts[0]`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `postContent` list of each user by doing;

```
db.Users.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Posts",
      localField: "userID",
      foreignField: "userID",
      as: "usersPosts"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      userPostContents: "$usersPosts.postContent"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      userID: 1,
      userPostContents: 1
    }
  }
])
```

Where, after doing the `$lookup`, you already know, we can just create an array with just the `postContent` field from `userPosts` array using [`addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/). Converting the array of objects into an array of strings.

See code on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tyVl0zZp-Hc)

Which will get you the list of `postContent` per `user`;

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5d93f338e602a10a38ad3588",
    "userID": "1",
    "userPostContents": [
      "hello world"
    ]
  }
]
```

---

Or if you'd like to get only the `postContent` of the first `post` per `user`, then change your `$project` stage to;

```
{
  $project: {
    userID: 1,
    userPostContent: {
      $arrayElemAt: [
        "$userPostContents",
        0
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which will get only the first `postContent`, like;

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5d93f338e602a10a38ad3588",
    "userID": "1",
    "userPostContent": "hello world"
  }
]
```

Check that on [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/caNj5Ori1pz) as well